# Login session in php

Tags: php, session

I have a code which provides me `session_timeout` after 10s of inactivity.

```
<?php
function isLoginSessionExpired() {
    $login_session_duration = 10; 
    $current_time = time(); 
    if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin_time']) and isset($_SESSION["user_id"])){  
        if(((time() - $_SESSION['loggedin_time']) > $login_session_duration)){ 
            return true; 
        } 
    }
}
?>
```

Help me out with editing the code so that `session_timeout` works even after refreshing page.

Means if user refresh page after `5s` then it should count the remaining time and **should not** start with `0s`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set first visit time of user as session.Then check the difference, try below code.

```
 function isLoginSessionExpired() {

    if(!isset($_SESSION['first_visit']))
    {
    $_SESSION['first_visit']=time();
    }else{
        $login_session_duration = 10; 
        $current_time = time(); 
        if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin_time']) and isset($_SESSION["user_id"])){  
            if(((time() - $_SESSION['first_visit']) > $login_session_duration)){ 
                return true; 
            } 
        }
    }
    }
```